power bi deskstop - calculated column result different in daxstudio
Carrying on from my previous question  here  
I still do not understand why pbi desktop table visual not giving the same result as per daxstudio.
Replicated test
--  parent - child rollup test
--  3 rows, 3 values, sumx
EVALUATE
--RollupTest = 
DATATABLE (
    "name", STRING,
    "child value", INTEGER,
    {
        { "test1", 1 },
        { "test2", 3 },
        { "test3", 1 } 
    }
)



EVALUATE
--rollup test =
VAR _rollup =
    SUMX (
        CALCULATETABLE (
            'RollupTest'
        ),
    'RollupTest'[child value]
    )
RETURN
    { _rollup }

Daxstudio

Yep, we get 5  (1+3+1)  correct
PBI Desktop

Nope, the  [rollup test]  column does not return 5 for each of the 3 rows.  Why?
No doubt there is a missunderstanding in my "row context" knowledge.  But to me the [rollup test] calculated column clearly states:

hit the entire 'rollup test' table again for each row

sum that temporary table


Which gives result of 5 for each of the 3 row iterations.  Does it not?
This question posted in pbi community  link

In a Calculated Column you will have Row Context, so you will only get that one row. To get the whole table then you'll need to use ALL or other filter function to remove the row context.
Eg:
rollup test =
  SUMX (
    ALL('RollupTest'),
    'RollupTest'[child value]
  )


Thanks Sam,  post your answer to the pbi community too if you like   https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/power-bi-deskstop-calculated-column-result-different-in/m-p/3956197#M1266114

Hey @garythomannCoGC ,
This measure 
rollup test = 
VAR _rollup =
    SUMX (
        // CALCULATETABLE (
            // ALLSELECTED(
                'RollupTest'
        //     )
        // )
        , 'RollupTest'[child value]
    )
RETURN
    { _rollup }
    enter code here

returns this (see attached image):

If you look closely, you will realize that I removed the CALCULATETABLE, but at the same I have added ALLSELECTED inside the CALCULATETABLE.
When
SUMX( <table> , ...
is used inside a calculated column "table" is reflecting the complete table because there is no filter context (at least not at the beginning).
When
SUMX( CALCULATETABLE(<table>) , ...
is used inside a calculated column: CALCULATETABLE is transforming the existing row context into a filter context; as the row context is defined by all columns, the filtered table contains only a single row, hence the SUMX returns the value of the current row.
When
SUMX( CALCULATETABLE(ALLSELECTED(<table>)) , ...
is used inside a calculated column: ALLSELECTED is returning ALL rows for each iteration of SUMX.
All the above is described here: MDX and DAX topics: The Logic behind the Magic of DAX Cross Table Filtering (mdxdax.blogspot.com), please be warned, this article is not an easy one.
One of the many essential parts inside of this article is the "four-step" execution, which is performed whenever there is a CALCULATE or a CALCULATETABLE.
Hopefully, this provides some additional insights.
Regards,
Tom
P.S.: this is my original answer from here: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/power-bi-deskstop-calculated-column-result-different-in/m-p/3956197#M1266114

Cheers Tom for providing a comprehensive answer that helped me to solve my issue that this post extends from, many thanks
